# Finding parity check matrix for linear code

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coding-theory

I have a generator matrix:

```
0 2 1 2 0
2 1 1 0 1
2 2 0 1 1
```

V is a linear code over GF(3) determined by this matrix. I'm trying to find a parity check matrix for V. Now, n = 5. I then row reduced to reduced echelon form and got:

```
1 0 1 1 0
0 1 2 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

So Dim k = 3.  The code I have right now is V = (5, 3).

I'm confused on what to do next. Normally the matrix I have would be in this form:

```
1 0 0|other numbers here 
0 1 0|
0 0 1|
```

and I could just do the -P^T | In-k

I know I should have a 2 x 5 matrix. But the identity matrix isn't there, did I do something wrong?

EDIT: Wait, you can swap columns can't you? In that case I can swap the 3rd and 5th column to put the generator matrix in standard form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the
$$
G=(I|P)\quad \implies \quad H=(-P^T|I)
$$
process as follows, when putting $G$ into reduced row echelon form fails to produce a leading identity block.

1. Put an identity matrix block into those columns that won't have a leading one.
2. Spread that $-P^T$-block into the remaining columns.

From your generator matrix
$$
G=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}1& 0& 1& 1& 0\\    
0& 1& 2& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
the process gives
$$
H=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
-1&-2&1&0&-0\\
-1&-1&0&1&-0
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
2&1&1&0&0\\
2&2&0&1&0
\end{array}\right).
$$
The form of $H$ on the left has those minus signs in place, but of course we get rid of them in the final answer.

By all means check that the equation $GH^T=0$ holds when you are done.