# How to generate LDPC parity check matrix from non-systematic to systematic by Gauss-elimination over GF(2)

Tags: matrices, coding-theory

Please anyone explain me how Gauss-Jordan elimination (over GF(2)) can be applied to a matrix of any dimension. I have searched over the Internet but i am not clear with concept of Gauss-Jordan elimination (over GF(2)). I need fruitful help from anyone

I am working with KINTEX board for LDPC encoding and decoding.Through Vivado HLS, I need to transform a parity-check matrix H (that only consists of ones and zeros) from a non-standard to a standard form. Here below you may find sample of non-standard parity check matrix in which Gauss-Jordan elimination (over GF(2)) can be applied.

This is my example H matrix. How Gauss-Jordan elimination (over GF(2)) can be applied to example H matrix. Explain me with logic.

H=[1 1 0 0 1 0;
   1 0 0 1 0 1;
   1 1 1 0 0 1 ];

Expected Systematic H matrix. Given a particular parity-check matrix, rearrange by Gauss-elimination so that H = [I_r|h], that is, so that H begins with an r by r identity matrix.

Hsys=   [1 0 0 1 0 1;
        0 1 0 1 1 1;
        0 0 1 0 1 1];

Comment: It is the usual algorithm to put the matrix into reduced row echelon form that you learned in linear algebra. Mind you, when dealing with production level LDPC codes you most likely don't want to do it this way. There is no reason to think that the systematic check matrix would have low density, and you may end up with a large matrix that has thousands of non-zero bits per check column, meaning that you will need to perform quite a few operation per encoded bit (and store that huge matrix). Of course, this may not be relevant to you.

Comment: Oh, and if the row echelon form doesn't have that identity block, then you also need to swap columns changing the bit order. Or, [do this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1486649/11619)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

Gauss-Jordan elimination over any field is exactly the same as Gauss-Jordan elimination over the reals, except that you do the arithmetic in the field.
In the case of $GF(2)$ it's even easier because you never have to worry about division.